# Question about replace charts with Regex (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to convert the character before ' + to ' itself to "" and Nothing is happens
Anyone know why?

```py
test_list = ["rrr'rrr"]
rep = [i.replace('\w\'', '') for i in test_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular exrpessions are handler with re in python

```
import re

test_list = ["rrr'rrr"]
rep = [re.sub('\w\'', '\'',i) for i in test_list]

print(rep)
```